# What causes dashboard indicators go off, ABS and brake indicator on intermittently?

Tags: brakes, abs, dashboard, indicators

I have a 2009 Toyota Camry.  We just replaced the alternator and battery a month ago.  Since this morning we have been having an intermittent dashboard indicator problem while driving:

The rpm, and speedometer both show zero.

The temperature indicator shows cold.

The ABS and brake indicators are on.

See attached photo.

This condition lasts for 10 to 20 seconds, then all indicators go back to normal.

It's hard to predict when it happens, but mostly just while driving.

I checked the brakes, engine, and coolant.  All are fine.  I think it is a loose cable somewhere.  What could be the cause?  These intermittent problems are toughest to diagnose.

Comment: Could be a communication issue, any codes in any module?

Comment: No codes. I suspect a connection issue.

Comment: In any module? or just the ECM? Anecdotally I work on a lot of Camry's in that year range and have never had to pull the cluster for a comm or connector issue. Any aftermarket equipment installed in the car? Any recent water intrusion? If the ABS and brake lights are coming there is probably a code.

Answer (score 3):

Often your type of problem is caused by a loss of ground to the dash. I'm not familar with your vehicle but you might try jumping a good ground to the dashboard when the problem occurs.